# Sorting posts and replies

Tags: sql

My table of posts has a post ID and a reply_to columns, like this:

```
1 null
2 null
3 1
4 2
5 1
```

As you can see post 5 is a reply to a post 1 for example. I am trying to construct an SQL query that would sort the SELECT so that replies go after the post they refer to. Otherwise sorted by ID. There is no nesting, the parent post is is always a reply to NULL.

In this example the result would be:

```
1 null
3 1
5 1
2 null
4 2
```

I feel like I must do something with minimum of id, replyto, maybe:

```
SELECT id, replyto from posts ORDER BY LEAST(id, replyto)
```

But it puts all root posts on the top

```
+------+---------+
| id   | replyto |
+------+---------+
|    1 |    NULL |
|    2 |    NULL |
|    3 |       1 |
|    5 |       1 |
|    4 |       2 |
+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured I can use `CASE`

```
SELECT * from posts
   ORDER BY LEAST(
      CASE WHEN ISNULL(replyto) THEN id ELSe replyto END, id
   );
```

(Why I always find a solution just after I ask a question here)